# VBA how to check row numbers whether they are even

Tags: excel, vba

The code functions for invalid part number when checking firstDigit ranges. Now when the code is actually a valid part number I need to check a new set of ranges for whether they are even or odd.

```
Option Explicit

 Sub PartNumber()

 Dim xCell As Range

 For Each xCell In Range("firstDigit")
 If xCell Like WorksheetFunction.Rept("[A-Z]", Len(xCell)) Then

'I decided to make digits a new sub to make the code look simpler.

   Call Digits
Else
    xCell.Offset(0, 2) = "Invalid Part Number"
   xCell.Offset(0, 2).Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If
Next xCell

End Sub
```

This is the part where I want to check if it is even or odd

```
Sub Digits()
Dim xxCell As Range
For Each xxCell In Range("productNumbers")
If xxCell = Even Then
    xxCell.Offset(0, 1) = "Ours"
    Else
    xxCell.Offset(0, 1) = "Theirs"
End if
Next xxCell
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need VBA for that: `=IF(MOD(ROW(),2),"Odd","Even")`

Comment: @Comintern, there actually is an ISEVEN worksheet function.

Comment: So you want to check two things before giving an output right? You want to know if the product is alpha only AND if the product is on a even row? Is that what you need?

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the *column index Mod 2* equals zero (aka Is False).

```
Sub Digits()

    Dim xxCell As Range
    For Each xxCell In Range("productNumbers")
      If Not xxCell.Column Mod 2 Then
          xxCell.Offset(0, 1) = "Ours"
      Else
          xxCell.Offset(0, 1) = "Theirs"
      End if
    Next xxCell

End Sub
```

Comment: That code doesn't work. It still states a run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: What worksheet is the *productNumbers* defined range on?

Comment: productNumbers worked once I tweaked the range name. The problem now is when I executed this code it turned every single row in column D into Ours

Comment: some were white some were yellow too.

Comment: Your question's title was about columns. If it is about rows then change xxCell.Column to xxCell.Row.

Comment: Row helped a bit to where theirs and ours showed up. There is a huge problem though. When this Digits executes, then it overwrites the boxes that should say invalid part number. However, the boxes that should be yellow are yellow.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot see your computer screen and have absolutely no idea what you're on about beyond the fact that this newer problem has nothing to do with your original question.

Comment: also, when it executes, it just makes theirs and ours repeat. There isn't an actual reason why they are executing

Comment: It does have exactly to do with what I asked as when this code executes with what you say it doesn't actually check the numbers if they are even or odd. It is just making every other row either theirs or ours.

Comment: Try changing xxCell.Row to xxCell.Value

Answer (score 0):

### The logic here is:

If the product number is ALPHA and the product number is EVEN then `Ours` - *Green*
If the product number is ALPHA and the product number is ODD then `Theirs`  - *Red*
If the product number is NON-ALPHA then `Invalid Product Number` - *Yellow*

*It may help you get solutions without confusion if you just state the logic you want to implement when you show your code*

---

No need to declare new ranges. Just pass the cell you are on in your first cell down to the next sub.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PartNumber()

Dim xCell As Range

For Each xCell In Range("firstDigit")
    If xCell Like WorksheetFunction.Rept("[A-Z]", Len(xCell)) Then
        Digits xCell
    Else
        xCell.Offset(0, 2) = "Invalid Part Number"
        xCell.Offset(0, 2).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
Next xCell
End Sub
```

```
Sub Digits(xCell)

For Each xCell In Range("productNumbers")
    If xCell Mod 2 = 0 Then
        xCell.Offset(0, 1) = "Ours"
        xCell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = vbGreen
    Else
        xCell.Offset(0, 1) = "Theirs"
        xCell.Offset(0, 1) = vbRed
    End If
Next xCell

End Sub
```